# Bright flash when resuming from sleep, ubuntu unity

Tags: unity, 15.10, suspend, brightness

Hi as the titles says really, I'm getting a really bright flash of the screen pre-suspend, when returning from sleep. Then it will load the lock screen at the brightness level I've set.

Any way to stop this flash returning from sleep?

Answer (score 1):

- Open your favorite text editor with `sudo` (command-line) or `pkexec` privilege; e.g. `pkexec gedit`
- paste the following script

> ```
> #!/bin/bash  
> case "$1" in
>     hibernate|suspend)
>         cat /sys/class/backlight/*/actual_brightness > /tmp/saved_brightness
>         ;;
>     thaw|resume)
>         cat /tmp/saved_brightness > /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness
>         ;; 
> esac
> ```

- save as `/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_brightness_recall`
- ensure it is executable with `sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_brightness_recall`
- Attempt to suspend. If it doesn't work, attempt to reboot and test again

Comment: thanks for the reply, I've given it a shot and rebooted, but still the same problem. It seems a lot quicker to go from the pre-suspend screen to the lock screen but that's about it.

Comment: @saph_top i noticed i had typo there. The brightness files in tmp folder didn't match. I will edit that. Point is , brightness should be stored into same file and restored from same one. Please try that again once i edit

Comment: No change unfortunately. If it makes any difference since installing I've been unable to use the `brightness up` `brightness down` commands from the terminal. `command brightness not found`

Comment: There is no such command in terminal. Ok what do you have in /sys/class/blacklight ?

Comment: `intel_backlight` and in that:

`actual_brightness  
brightness  
max_brightness  
subsystem  
uevent
bl_power           
device      
power
type`

Comment: So it should be working. And changing brightness with function keys works ok ?

Comment: Thing is originally my laptop was a chromebook with ChromeOS. So when I installed something called SeaBios to allow for the complete removal of ChromeOS a lot of the function keys didn't really carry over. I have no home button, page down, delete key etc. But a programme `brightness-indicator` allows me to control brightness using the command `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/indicator-brightness/indicator-brightness-adjust --down` by mapping that to a specific key.  No worries, thanks for your help, it's a fairly minor problem in the scheme of things.